# Automapper - map from List item property to List of int

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, automapper

Using .NET Core with EF and Automapper. How can I map the Property of a List Item to a List of same type as the Property?

I'd like to map the `int JobId` from each `Job` in `Address.JobHistory` to the `List<int> JobHistory` of my `AddressDTO`

Address Class

```
public class Address {
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    ...other properties...
    public List<Job> JobHistory { get; set; }
}
```

AddressDTO Class

```
public class AddressDTO {
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    ...other properties...
    public List<int> JobHistory { get; set; }
}
```

Job Class

```
public class Job {
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    ...other properties...
    public Address JobAddress { get; set; }
}
```

AddressController Automapper Config (this is where I need to make the magic happen, but below is what I have now)

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
            cfg.CreateMap<Address, AddressDTO>()
                ...map other properties...
                .ForMember(dto => dto.JobHistory, opt => opt.MapFrom(addr => addr.JobHistory));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I'll need to use a [Custom Type Converter](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-type-converters.html) and supply my own method to do the conversion.

Comment: Yes, but that applies everywhere. You could solve it locally with `MapFrom(addr => addr.JobHistory.Select(j=>j.JobId))`. Whatever fits best.

Comment: **lightbulb illuminates overhead**
That makes way more sense and is way less code. Thanks!